# Invalid left-hand side in assignment for simple login script

Tags: javascript

I have to build a simple login script for a js class.

I cannot get the loop to work. Everytime I type in any info it gives me "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

When the login button is clicked the getData function gets the values of the boxes then passes them to the logon function that checks against the array. That's where the script stops. If I change the = in the if statement to == it will accept the last valid login f the array but none of the others.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userLogins = [{user:"user1", password:"pass1"},{user:"user2", password:"pass2"},{user:"user3", password:"pass3"}]
var success = null;
function logon(user, pass) {
    userok = false;
    for (i = 0; i < userLogins.length; i++)
    { 
        if(pass = userLogins[i].password && user = userLogins[i].user )
        {
            success = true;
        }
        else
        {
            success = false;
        }
    }
    secret(success);
}

function getData() {
    var user = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    logon(user, password);
}

function secret(auth){
    if(auth)
    {
        show('success');
        hide('login');
    }
    else
    {
        show('error');
        hide('login');
    }
}

function show(show) {
    document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
}
function hide(hide) {
    document.getElementById(hide).className = "hide";
}
```

Comment: `=` is for assignments in JavaScript, you need to use `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I change the = in the if statement to == it will accept the last valid login f the array but none of the others.

`=` is the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

`==` is the [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

You're confusing the two. You want the latter. Otherwise, your assigning the value which results returns the value itself (often a *true* value).

Per the comments, there's also the *strict equality operator*. For the difference between `==` and `===` [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use) will blow your mind.

Comment: `===` to prevent coercion surprises

Comment: @Matt Whipple, indeed. Baby steps :)

Comment: I tried changing the `=` to `==` and `===` but the script only matches the last element in the array. user3 and pass3 work, but the others do not.

Comment: I guarantee you don't want to use `=`. How are you calling `logon(user, pass)`? You have another problem, unrelated to the `==`.